# Android: NAT table: “FIX ME! impliment getnetbyaddr() bionic/libc/bionic/stubs.c:444” what does it mean and how to fix it

Tags: android, iptables, nat

Background:

I'm trying to setup a VPN server on android phone. For, this I am trying to use android sample application ToyVpn.

To setup the server, I have to add following rule in the nat table

```
#Pick a range of private addresses and perform NAT over eth0.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

But I got following error:

```
 iptables v1.4.14: can't initialize iptables table -nat: Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
 Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I do not have any prior knowledge of working with the iptables. But, I searched about it, and replaced "-A" by "-I" i.e. instead of appending rule in the table now I'm inserting rule in the table, because my table was empty.

Problem:

The problem is that, Now in the nat table there is following message:

```
FIX ME! impliment getnetbyaddr() bionic/libc/bionic/stubs.c:444
```

above the rule that I inserted. The rule is appearing as:

```
MASQUERADE all -- 10.0.0.0/8 anywhere
```

Can anyone please guide me about what I did wrong and how can I fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you did anything wrong - the message seems to indicate that a critical libc function is not implemented in bionic, the C library used by Android.

I do not think there is really anything you can do, short of implementing the function in bionic and then possibly compiling most of an Android system from source.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the source code..., does it mean to use a customized kernel?

Comment: libc is separate from the kernel, so changing the kernel won't affect libc.  If you want to get that function implemented in Android, submit a patch to the Android AOSP team.