# Android VpnService - How to forward intercepted internet traffic ?

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp, vpn

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766405/android-vpnservice-to-capture-packets-wont-capture-packets) and created Vpn interface using VpnService.  On adding forward route as "0.0.0.0" all internet traffic is forwarded to Vpn Interface.  I could read the packets, access protocol, destination ip and port.

Now I am trying to forward the packets to its destination via tcp sockets.  But socket connection fails with connection timed out.

```
exception: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /74.125.227.114 (port 443): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

Note: When I try socket connection with same ip and port, but without Vpn, it gets connected. Not able to figure out where I am going wrong?

Pasting the code below:

```
public class VpnServiceEx extends VpnService implements Handler.Callback, Runnable {
    private static final String TAG = "VpnServiceEx";

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Thread mThread;

    private ParcelFileDescriptor mInterface;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // The handler is only used to show messages.
        if (mHandler == null) {
            mHandler = new Handler(this);
        }

        // Stop the previous session by interrupting the thread.
        if (mThread != null) {
            mThread.interrupt();
        }

        // Start a new session by creating a new thread.
        mThread = new Thread(this, "TestVpnThread");
        mThread.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mThread != null) {
            mThread.interrupt();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
        if (message != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, message.what, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        Log.i(TAG,"running vpnService");
        try {
            runVpnConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Log.e(TAG, "Got " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                mInterface.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }
            mInterface = null;

            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(R.string.disconnected);
            Log.i(TAG, "Exiting");
        }
    }


    private void runVpnConnection() {

        configure();

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());

        // Allocate the buffer for a single packet.
        ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(32767);

        Socket tcpSocket = new Socket();

        boolean ok = true;

        // We keep forwarding packets till something goes wrong.
        while (ok) {
            // Assume that we did not make any progress in this iteration.
            try {
                // Read the outgoing packet from the input stream.
                int length = in.read(packet.array());
                if (length > 0) {

                    Log.i(TAG,"packet received");
                    packet.limit(length);

                    String serverIP = getDestinationIP(packet);
                    int port = getDestinationPort(packet, getHeaderLength(packet));

                    Log.d(TAG, "destination IP: " + serverIP + " port: " + port);

                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
                    SocketAddress socketadd= new InetSocketAddress(serverAddr, port);

                    tcpSocket.connect(socketadd);  *****// this fails******

                    OutputStream outBuffer = tcpSocket.getOutputStream();
                    outBuffer.write(packet.array());
                    outBuffer.flush();
                    outBuffer.close();
                    packet.clear();
                    ok = false;
                }

                if (tcpSocket.isConnected()) {
                    InputStream inBuffer = tcpSocket.getInputStream();
                    byte[] bufferOutput = new byte[32767];
                    inBuffer.read(bufferOutput);
                    if (bufferOutput.length > 0) {
                        String recPacketString = new String(bufferOutput,0,bufferOutput.length,"UTF-8");
                        Log.d(TAG , "recPacketString : " + recPacketString);
                        out.write(bufferOutput);
                    }

                    inBuffer.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG,"exception: " + e.toString());
                ok = false;
            }

        }
    }


    private void configure() {
        // If the old interface has exactly the same parameters, use it!
        if (mInterface != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Using the previous interface");
            return;
        }

        // Configure a builder while parsing the parameters.
        Builder builder = new Builder();
        builder.setMtu(1500);
        builder.addAddress(getLocalIpAddress(), 24);
        builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);  // to intercept packets
        try {
            mInterface.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }

        mInterface = builder.establish();
    }
```

Comment: Now I get to know that why I am not able to forward the packets through sockets.  On adding vpn route table entry with ip address(0.0.0.0) is causing this.  To confirm I only added specific address and could see socket connection is success for all other address "except" the address added in route table.  But to intercept all the traffic I couldn't find a better way than adding route table entry as (0.0.0.0).  Does any one know?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that it will work in case you want to do bi-directional communication. Your TUN interface is also sending Layer 3 packets and your socket is L4 so the way you're piping the data to the tun interface may not work unless you craft your own TCP+IP packets

Comment: could you add the definition of your methods getDestinationIP, getDestinationPort, getHeaderLength. I wanted to understand how IP Packets works. Thanks.

Comment: @shashank: were you finally able to solve this problem ? Also please add the code for extracting destination ip and port.

Comment: could you add the definition of your methods ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to protect the socket from being rerouted with `VpnService.protect(Socket)` as stated here: [How to use VPN in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233477/how-to-use-vpn-in-android/#answers)

Answer (score 2):

The data you read from the FileInputStream is contains IPHeader and TCP/UDP Header, then you put them in a socket, this will add another IPHeader and TCP/UDP Header on it. So the server side will get the data witch contains IPHeader and TCP/UDP Header, but it think the data is Application data. So you could not connect the server.