# Java VPN Connection

Tags: java, android, networking, vpn

I have to create an Android app that connect to a Server with a VPN.
I read this topic: [How to use VPN in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233477/how-to-use-vpn-in-android)

And I found that "There is no standard mechanism in place for setting up a connection to a VPN server. ToyVpn simply communicates over a socket using raw TCP packets. You can either implement an existing protocol (see RFC 4026) like OpenVPN has done or write something yourself."

It is still true today? Are there any solutions to easily connect to a Server with a VPN?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444757/how-to-configure-vpn-programatically

Comment: @Budius so I need to implement the OpenVPN on the server?

Answer (score -2):

```
Intent vi = VpnService.prepare(MainActivity.this);

if (vi != null) {
   startActivityForResult(vi, 3);
}
```

Comment: Add your server and fix it and use